# Complex join between two tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to help on the below complex join scenario. Please guide me.

Table 1

```
Patient_ID  Service_code Tablet
-------------------------------
1            120         cnr
1            230         pmr
1            520         ksr
3            212         dnr
3            332         psr
4            412         vrr
4            333         zyr
```

Table 2

```
Product_service_cd     Rank
----------------------------
120                    1
230                    2
520                    1
212                    13
332                    5
333                    2
```

Desired output

```
patient_id  service_code  Tablet
--------------------------------
1           520           ksr
3           332           psr
4           333           zyr
```

Single patient has multiple tables, so we need to choose one table for each patient based Highest rank (1 being highest) using conditions below:

1. If both service Id have same ran choose `max(service_code)`
2. If a patient has 2 service Id, choose the highest rank among the service IDs
3. If the service Id is missing in table 2 then have rank default as 100

My query:

```
select 
    t1.patient_id, t1.service_id
from
    table1 t1
where 
    t1.service_code = (select a.service_code, min(b.rank) 
                       from table1 a
                       left join table2 
                       group by a.service_code);
```

Also trying to find how to assign default rank as 100 if service code is not found in table2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to sort the rows for each patient, according to the ordering you decide. Then, it's a matter of picking the first one per patient

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    a.*,
    row_number() over(partition by patient_id
      order by coalesce(b.rank, 100), a.service_code desc
    ) as rn
  from table1 a
  left join table2 b on b.product_service_code = a.service_code
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you very much but table1 is a temporary table and it seems partition by will not work on a temporary table. Could you please suggest with modifying for a temporary table?

Comment: @PremkumarV That would depend on the specific database you are using, and you didn't mention which one was it. Can you specify what's the database and how are you creatng the temporary table?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! The previous query that you shared worked fine. You are an "Absolute Legend!!"